# Best way to save/update a resource with ($watch or save button, etc..)

Tags: angularjs

Currently I run into the following problem,
we are working on a form heavy application and wanted a good user experience so we tried to stop have a save / update button everywhere.

Currently we try to `$watch` every Form Change, but this won't work correctly since it updates the scope when the model gets updated which causing problems on Decimal / Money Values.

What would you prefer? Still the messy `save` button or maybe something like Gmail did?

What are good methods to do this without save buttons.

**/* EDITED */**
Currently we use this method to update our form.
It first copys the scope in an object and checks if it is the same than the object that is set after the date got pulled.

```
$scope.$watch('task', function(scope) {
console.log($scope.updateForm);
scopeObject = angular.copy(scope);
if(scope !== undefined) {
  if(!(_.isEqual(scopeObject, mainObject))){

    //scope_copy.request_date = $filter('date')(new Date(scope.request_date), 'fullDate');
    console.log('update');
    scope.$update({pk: $routeParams.taskId}, function() {
      scope.request_date = $filter('date')(scope.request_date);
      mainObject = angular.copy(scope);
    });
    mainObject = angular.copy(scope);
  }
}
}, true);
```

currently i think this code is somehow messy since it can't update decimal numbers.
but currently i don't have a better solution. (i don't want to use a Button to submit the form, it should be done interactivly).

Comment: add a lean example of what you currently have so others can use that as a direction for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: kk, i currently edited it.

Comment: does it have to save every change made or a solution using a timeout would be acceptable (like every 30 seconds, you check the new changes, then update it) ?

Comment: 30 Seconds is a very long time, i think. 
I'm still not sure if it would gave more usability if i stop `$watch` and use a event if i leave the focus or if somebody press enter.
still i think a save button is just unfriendly.

Comment: I mean maybe i should use a `$timeout` and just check if the model changed before ~5 sec if yes, wait another 5sec if it won't change. but still i would have some things like `$timeout` or a wait.
will timeouts be interrupted if the `$route` or controller changes?

Comment: I said 30 seconds because I don't know what you have to modify, but it's not the main problem, it can be customized. Actually I think the way the user modifies the data is important, you mentionned gMail, if you want something like that, they use timeout to save changes every X seconds, then they react to the focus/blur of the different fields etc... I think you should do a combination of all these events if you really want to save on each user interaction

Comment: hm that's a really good advise.
i also thought about websockets, to make the interaction a little bit smoother, but since i then need to think about statefullness it's really hard to achieve in a cluster.
i think at the moment i will use the $timeout and check blur/focus on every field i need to update.